# Why the second argument of function become never

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, generics, types

want to create simple generic interface for function, that accepts interface of object and first argument is key of object and second is key2 of object by object[key].

Here my solution

```
type Test<T extends Object, K extends keyof T = keyof T, V extends keyof T[K] = keyof T[K]> = (key: K, key2: V) => void
```

Object

```
const convertFunctionsMap = {
  ms: {
    h: millisecondsToHours,
    s: millisecondsToSeconds,
    m: millisecondsToMinutes
  },
  s: {
    h: secondsToHours,
    ms: secondsToMilliseconds,
    m: secondsToMinutes
  },
  m: {
    ms: minutesToMilliseconds,
    s: minutesToSeconds,
    h: minutesToHours
  },
  h: {
    ms: hoursToMilliseconds,
    s: hoursToSeconds,
    m: hoursToMinutes
  }
}
```

But I got

[image: Result]

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-leaf-cuz51r?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't how to explain, but i know it works

```
interface Test<T> {
  <K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]>(key: K1, key2: K2): void;
}

const convertFunctionsMap = {
  ms: {
    h: 1,
    s: 2,
    m: 3
  },
  s: {
    h: 1,
    ms: 2,
    m: 3
  },
  m: {
    ms: 1,
    s: 2,
    h: 3
  },
  h: {
    ms: 1,
    s: 2,
    m: 3
  }
}
const getIn2: Test<typeof convertFunctionsMap> = ()=> {}
getIn2('ms', 'h');
```

Comment: Year, it works, but it is really intresting why, I can't pass object as generic argument of function. Thank you btw.

Comment: type V2 = (typeof convertFunctionsMap)[keyof typeof convertFunctionsMap]; you can see type V2 is {
    h: number;
    s: number;
    m: number;
} | {
    h: number;
    ms: number;
    m: number;
} | {
    ms: number;
    s: number;
    h: number;
} | {
    ms: number;
    s: number;
    m: number;
}; they have no same key, so K2 is never